# How to get ReactContext in a Android Service?

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent, android-service, android-context

I want to start my service from ReactNative code.
Here is the module I use to bridge.

```
public class HeartbeatModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "Heartbeat";
    private static ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

    public HeartbeatModule(@Nonnull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
      super(reactContext);
      this.reactContext = reactContext;
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
      return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @ReactMethod
     public void startService() {
     // Starting the heartbeat service

     this.reactContext.startService(new Intent(this.reactContext, HeartbeatService.class));
     }


    @ReactMethod
    public void stopService() {
        // Starting the heartbeat service

        this.reactContext.stopService(new Intent(this.reactContext, HeartbeatService.class));
    }
}
```

My question is how can I access this reactContext in my service.
And how to sustain it when the service restarts.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can start the service via react code . start Service method which is annotated by   React Method will be available in react code .there should be index js file in your code and try to import package make call to start service.

Comment: Recontext can not be accessible to service instead of that you can you use Broadcast receiver in service and get the data from service to ReactContextBaseJavaModule .

Comment: It wont work. because he is asking in JAVA code, you can not send ReactContext to Service directly

Comment: @Manisha, is this the only solution to the problem?